# javascript to give class (1) when scroll to a div and remove class (1) change to class (2) when leave the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animate.css

How to make js when i reach or scroll to  **div id hover1** give **class "animated fadeInDown"**

when i scroll down or leave  **div id hover1** change **class"animated fadeInDown"** To **class"animated fadeOutUp"**

I'm using `animate.css` for the class

Here the example (animate.css and jquery already include):

```css
body {
  height: 9999px;
}

.kotak {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/> content
<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>

<div id="hover1" class="kotak"><br/>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;<br/><br/>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;<br/><br/>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;<br/><br/>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;<br/><br/>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;<br/><br/>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;<br/></div>

content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>
```

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/rickwijaya/pen/MmjZPm)

Comment: you can use $(window).scrollTop()

Comment: can you give the example ? i'm new at js

Comment: $(document).scroll(function() {    
var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
if (scroll >= 500) {
setTimeout('$(".nav").addClass("navnewclass")',1000);
}
});

Comment: so if i want to make the fade out i need to copy that and change the scroll to <= the div height ? and what set timeout mean ? and 1000 mean ? .thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your JS pane on code pen.

```
$( "#hover1" ).on( "mouseover", function() {
  $(this).removeClass('animated fadeOutUp').addClass('animated fadeInDown')
});

$( "#hover1" ).on( "mouseout", function() {
  $(this).removeClass('animated fadeInDown').addClass('animated fadeOutUp')
});
```

Comment: its work but there like glitch sometimes the animation work sometimes its not. is because my css ? thanks for the help